# I have submitted my resignation but the employer does not acknowledge receipt

Tags: resignation

My role within the company was changed and during the consultation process, I was suspended pending investigation. I submitted my resignation after not hearing from them for 5 days, the message has been read, but no acknowledgement of receipt is forthcoming, or attempts to start the discussion process. The resignation letter was delivered and received 48 hours ago

What should by next step be?

Comment: How long since you submitted your resignation?

Comment: do you live in a location or work under a contract where acknowledgement or acceptance of your resignation has legal implications?

Comment: This needs a location tag.

Comment: How did you submit your resignation? I guess email since you say you know it has been read (read receipt?)

Comment: why where you suspended during consultation? this seams very odd did you do something silly and are now facing disciplinary action

Answer (score 2):

Send them another message giving a date for the end of your employment. State clearly that you will cease to work for them after that date. Make sure you have evidence that it was received, e.g. registered mail or email reading receipt.

That's all you need to do. If they fail to act it's their problem. Concentrate on your next job.

Comment: "Make sure you have evidence that it was received" - I wouldn't bother (unless you are concerned that it might not actually *be* received).  If he has given notice, his employment *will* end.  Sending the message with a date is a good way of reminding them you are serious, but doesn't actually change anything.

Comment: The proof of receipt is important if they turn around and claim that the questioner didn't give proper notice later. Also note that you likely used the wrong pronouns.

Comment: Oops!  Apologies to the OP (that was careless).  Receipt of the additional method isn't relevant to whether notice was properly given or not.  It cannot be the notice - it is the *original* message which is the notice (and which she *does* have evidence of receipt for).

Comment: Say his future employer wants to contact them to check that he actually worked there. They might say "he was here for 2 years and was fired for non-attendance". Having proof of receipt would be very useful then.

Answer (score 1):

> The resignation letter was delivered and received 48 hours ago.

Presuming that you are at-will, it is courtesy to give a two week notice period. But some companies can decide to terminate immediately.

As it was sent and received, it is out of your hands right now. Notices are effective upon sending. It is presumed that it was sent and received successfully. It is not required for your employers to notify you that they've received it. You keep showing up for that two week notice period out of courtesy, but make sure that your presence is wanted by management. Otherwise you are wasting your time.

> What should by next step be?

Find your next job.

Comment: "Presuming that you are at-will" - why presume that?

Comment: Because if OP signed a contract, it would be pretty clear what the exit process would be. It would be detailed in the contract.

Comment: @FrankFYC You're heavily assuming the OP is from the US or another country that deals with at will. Most Western countries don't do that. This quesiton needs further clarification before it can be properly answered

Comment: @Draken Would a good suggestion that I delete the question and allow OP to revise the question to include a location?

Comment: @FrankFYC : Note that the OP says he was suspended pending investigation, so he should *not* turn up for work.  Ignoring that, the only difference that a contractual notice period would make is that "You keep showing up for that two week notice period out of courtesy," becomes "You keep showing up for your contractual notice period".  (And in either case I would add "and then stop showing up")

Comment: @MartinBonner I might've misunderstood that. Suspended Pending Investigation =/= a person is suspend only after an investigation?

Comment: "Suspended Pending Investigation" == "We are investigating these allegations. We don't know if we can trust you, so while we find out please don't come in to work - but we will continue to pay you."  After an investigation you don't suspend someone; you fire them, or demote them, or exonerate them.

Answer (score -1):

> What should by next step be?

Do this:

1. Forward the email you sent to resign once again, with a brief message stating that "**I haven't gotten a response to this yet**" to your manager, HR person, and CC a personal email address of your own.
2. If you want to re-enforce step one, print out the email you sent in step one, and send it via some method where a signature is required for delivery.
3. And finally, picking up the phone and speaking your manager or HR representative is also appropriate.

This will give you two points of proof (if you need the second one is up to you).  At this point proceed with your plan of resigning, and I assume starting a new role elsewhere.